# Python packages - import by class, not file

Tags: python, package

Say I have the following file structure:

```
app/
  app.py
  controllers/
    __init__.py
    project.py
    plugin.py
```

If app/controllers/project.py defines a class Project, app.py would import it like this:

```
from app.controllers.project import Project
```

I'd like to just be able to do:

```
from app.controllers import Project
```

How would this be done?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You need to put

```
from project import Project
```

in `controllers/__init__.py`.

Note that when [Absolute imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) become the default (Python 2.7?), you will want to add a dot before the module name (to avoid collisions with a top-level model named `project`), i.e.,

```
from .project import Project
```

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to exclude at all the ability to call `app.controllers.project.Project`, in order to avoid having redundant paths to the same object (having both `app.controllers.project.Project` and `app.controllers.Project` at this point)