# What could be some reasons why a class is not visible unless imported directly from a function?

Tags: python

Example:

```
import user

class Thing(object):

    def doSomething(self):

        u = user.User(1)
        print u.name

>>  UnboundLocalError: local variable 'user' referenced before assignment
```

But this works:

```
class Thing(object):

    def doSomething(self):

        import user
        u = user.User(1)
        print u.name
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit:

But this works:

```
import user as anothername

class Thing(object):

    def doSomething(self):

        u = anothername.User(1)
        print u.name
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [python import coding style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477096/python-import-coding-style)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you've posted is missing something, because it works fine as shown.

I'm guessing that your real code looks more like this:

```
import user

class Thing(object):

    def doSomething(self):
        u = user.User(1)
        print u.name
        # ...
        user = something
```

The problem is that by assigning to the local name `user` you've said that `user` is a local variable for the entire body of that function -- **even the code before the assignment**.  This means that the name `user` does *not* refer to your module in that function, it refers to a local variable. Trying to reference a local variable before it's been assigned a value results in the error you're seeing.

Using a local import works because part of what import does is assignment. ie: `import user` ensures that the "user" module has been imported, and assigns that module object to the name `user`.

The simple fix is to change the name of your local variable to something that doesn't shadow your import.

Comment: Eesh ok, I'm trying to figure out the relevant parts to post without posting a million classes / lines.

Comment: I was trying to figure out how that specific exception could be thrown instead of a `NameError`.  Try `import user as USER` and change all of the references in the source that is failing.  It might be easiest to triage that way.

Comment: You read my code without me having to paste it all -- thanks so much.  Really appreciate it.  This worked!