# Scope of imported modules/functions in Python

Tags: python, import, scope

I'm new here and am not 100% sure how to ask this question so I'll just dive right in.  Should I be using import statements at the beginning of every function I write that import all of the various modules/functions I need for that function's scope? i.e.

```
def func1()
    import os.path
    print func(2)
    do something with os.path

def func2()
    import os.path
    do something with os.path
```

Will this increase memory overheads, or other overheads, or is the import statement just mapping a local name to an already loaded object?  Is there are better way to do this?  (Links to tutorials etc. most welcome.  I've been looking for a while but can't find a good answer to this.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [python import coding style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477096/python-import-coding-style)

Comment: @S. Lott. The topvoted answer to that question is technically wrong. I added a new on to it. The problem is that the timing technique used is very flawed and doesn't account for the difference in cost between accessing a local and accessing a global.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The module will only be processed the first time it is imported; subsequent imports will only copy a reference to the local scope. It is however best style to import at the top of a module when possible; see PEP 8 for details.

Comment: @GlenS: Learn PEP8. The sooner you do, the sooner your code will look right to other Python coders.

Answer (score 10):

[Usually](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) all imports are placed at the beginning of the file. Importing a module in a function body will `import` a module in that scope only:

```
def f():
    import sys
    print 'f', sys.version_info

def g():
    print 'g', sys.version_info

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f() # will work
    g() # won't work, since sys hasn't been imported into this modules namespace
```

Comment: I mean, is sys.modules per thread or per process or per computer?