# Where to import modules

Tags: python

Lets say I have a module called **device** which contains a class called **ConfigureDevice**. Lets also say that I have a module called **comports** which defines my com ports in a class called **ComPorts** (enum in C).

Now, lets say that the constructor for **ConfigureDevice** takes an argument called comPorts. The question is, should I import **comports** at the beginning of the **device** module or should the code creating **ConfigureDevice** make this import?

So, should **import comports** occur here:

```
# device module
import serialwriter
import comports

class ConfigureDevice:
    def __init__(self, comPort):
        self.serialWriter = serialwriter.SerialWriter(comPort)
```

Or should I import it in the code that creates ConfigureDevice, like this:

```
import device
import comports

...

device.ConfigureDevice(comports.ComPorts.COM_1)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python import coding style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477096/python-import-coding-style)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should generally always put `import` at the top of the module, where Python programmers will expect to find it, because then any import errors will happen right when the program starts, instead of happening much later when a function is finally called. We generally only put `import` inside a function because (a) we are trying to avoid an awkward import loop among badly-designed modules, or (b) because we want to make a 3rd-party library optional so that you only need it if you call that function.

**Update:** Thank you for the code samples! Beyond my initial advice, that `import` always go at the top of a file, I can additionally now recommend that you remove the import of `comport` from your device module because, from what I can see, you never use the module there — I do not see the name `comport` anywhere in the device module code. In general, if you try removing an `import` statement from a file but the program still runs, the statement did not belong there in the first place. The [pyflakes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) program can help you find `import` statements that are no longer useful as your code evolves.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. I've added two examples to make my question more clear. In both examples the import is at the top, but which is correct?