# Saving a directory with a variable name

Tags: python, variables

```
Pn = input("Give the name of the Project.")

import shutil as sl
sl.copytree(r"C:\Users\Desktop\Automate\Template\C", r"C:\User\Desktop\{Pn}")
```

What I want to do is save a copy of directory in specific location with user defined name. This just saves it with {Pn} as its name.

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.format`

**Ex:**

```
Pn = input("Give the name of the Project.")

import shutil as sl
sl.copytree(r"C:\Users\Desktop\Automate\Template\C", r"C:\User\Desktop\{Pn}".format(Pn=Pn ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though Rakesh's answer is perfectly fine, if you're using Python >= 3.6, you can also use f-strings for shorter syntax (note the added ***f*** before the second string):

```
Pn = input("Give the name of the Project.")

import shutil as sl
sl.copytree(r"C:\Users\Desktop\Automate\Template\C", rf"C:\User\Desktop\{Pn}")
```

A couple more things to note:

- [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) suggests lowercase_with_underscore naming for variables, methods and functions (e.g. *Pn* should be *pn*)
- It is idiomatic to Python that variable names read as English rather than, obscured, low-level, shortened names (e.g. *pn* should be *project_name*) - see [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) for more such "philosophical" principles
- It is generally a good idea to have imports right on top of your program, since you can easily check out its dependencies and fail-fast on ImportError (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477096/python-import-coding-style/477107#477107) for more details)