# Using f2py on a Fortran code linked to PETSc

Tags: python, fortran, f2py, petsc

My question is related to this post:

[Including a compiled module in module that is wrapped with f2py (Minimum working example)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27270543/including-a-compiled-module-in-module-that-is-wrapped-with-f2py-minimum-working)

in which the poster was trying to compile a Fortran code (Test.f90) with f2py and link that to a pre-compiled library (or in my case, object, myex44f.o).  The answer enabled me to compile the Fortran code and generated the python module.

My problem is different from the above posters problem in that my object is linked to PETSc.  When I try to import my f2py-generated library into python, I get the error that it cannot locate 'VecDestroy', a PETSc subroutine.  My most recent attempt was:

f2py -c --fcompiler=gfortran -I. myex44f.o ../../../Codes/third_party/petsc/include/petsc/finclude/petscdef.h -m test Test.f90

Here is the code Test.f90:

```
subroutine test  
USE petsctest  
call mainsub  
end subroutine test
```

which calls `mainsub` from the module `petsctest`:

```
      module petsctest   !   Solves the linear system  J x = f
#include <petsc/finclude/petscdef.h>
      contains
      subroutine mainsub
      use petscksp; use petscdm
      Vec x,f
      Mat J
      DM da
      KSP ksp
      PetscErrorCode ierr
      call PetscInitialize(PETSC_NULL_CHARACTER,ierr)

      call DMDACreate1d(MPI_COMM_WORLD,DM_BOUNDARY_NONE,8,1,1,        &
     &  PETSC_NULL_INTEGER,da,ierr)
      call DMCreateGlobalVector(da,x,ierr)
      call VecDuplicate(x,f,ierr)
      call DMSetMatType(da,MATAIJ,ierr)
      call DMCreateMatrix(da,J,ierr)

      call ComputeRHS(da,f,ierr)
      call ComputeMatrix(da,J,ierr)

      call KSPCreate(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ksp,ierr)
      call KSPSetOperators(ksp,J,J,ierr)
      call KSPSetFromOptions(ksp,ierr)
      call KSPSolve(ksp,f,x,ierr)

      call MatDestroy(J,ierr)
      call VecDestroy(x,ierr)
      call VecDestroy(f,ierr)
      call KSPDestroy(ksp,ierr)
      call DMDestroy(da,ierr)
      call PetscFinalize(ierr)
      end
```

The error that I get is:

> > > import test Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in  ImportError: ./test.so: undefined symbol: vecdestroy_

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thank you very much for any help you can provide me.

**UPDATE:**
I generated the original `myex44f.o` object using the makefile provided with the PETSc examples.  Looking at the link line, I reasoned that I might need to link the petsc library when compiling with f2py.  My current attempt is:

`f2py -c --fcompiler=gfortran -m test Test.f90 -I. myex44f.o -I/home/costoich/Documents/AFPWork/Codes/third_party/petsc/include -I/home/costoich/Documents/AFPWork/Codes/third_party/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug/include -L/home/costoich/Documents/AFPWork/Codes/third_party/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug/lib -lpetsc`

This seems to be linking correctly during the compile steps (if I just write `-lpetsc` without the path the compiler fails).  However, when I type `ldd test.so`, I get:

`linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe09886000)
    libpetsc.so.3.7 => not found
    libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007fc315be5000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc31581b000)
    libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007fc3155dc000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc3152d3000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fc3150bc000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055a3fad27000)`

Do I need two use the link flags Wl,rpath?  f2py seems to not understand these.  Thank you for any comments.

**RESOLVED**
I found my issue.  I can't get f2py to accept the `-Wl,rpath` options, but if I define the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/costoich/Documents/AFPWork/Codes/third_party/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug/lib` everything works out.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: You must show the information you have, the steps leading to the error message and the error message itself. Also some code is appropriate.

Comment: Edit the question and put the code there. Dont forget the error message with the command that produced it.

Comment: Thanks again @VladimirF.  I have edited the post, though it is still not done correctly, I think it is a little more clear.  I appreciate the advice.

Comment: It looks like if the VecDestrou is not in the PETSC module you are using.

Comment: Are you able to run the code in Fortran only without f2py?

Comment: modules and f2py generally do not go well together. I recommend writing a wrapper, so that your module is only exposed to your fortran compiler and not f2py

Comment: That's not true, they work fine.

Comment: @VladimirF, the code does run in Fortran.  That was a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

@VladimirF, has a point.

> It looks like if the VecDestrou is not in the PETSC module you are using.

Seems to me following parts of PETSc are required in your module.

```
#include <petsc/finclude/petscsysdef.h>
#include <petsc/finclude/petscvecdef.h>
! Optional
#include <petsc/finclude/petscdef.h>
#include <petsc/finclude/petscdm.h>
#include <petsc/finclude/petscvec.h> 
#include <petsc/finclude/petscvec.h90>  
#include <petsc/finclude/petscmat.h>
#include <petsc/finclude/petscmat.h90>
! might be not completed
! Or
use petscksp
use petscdm
use petscvec
use petscmat 
!might be not completed
```

How to use PETSc with Fortran is diccussed [here](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Sys/UsingFortran.html), personally I go for option 2 in that page. Most of the existing PETSc examples are following option 2 as well.

Please let me clarify that **[I am not encouraging you to use `include` over `use`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15668209/2590800)**, that's the way I am used to do only. PETSc documentation has an example that using Fortran modules, for example [here](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/src/vec/vec/examples/tutorials/ex20f90.F90.html). So you can choose any of these methods/or have both optionally (please realize that preprocessor option in that example, PETSC_USE_FORTRAN_MODULES), but still need to add required modules depends on what you are using.