# Make a module out a bunch of .f source files

Tags: module, fortran, gfortran

I downloaded some Fortran source code which contains around 50 or so `.f` files.  Each `.f` file contains one subroutine or function.  I'd like to conveniently stuff all of these into a Fortran module `.mod` file.  Is there any way of doing this with gfortran (besides painstakingly writing out each sub/func prototype inside a module definition)?

Comment: You'll have to watch out for all manner of excitement when doing this.  I recall questions involving `external` when trying this.

Comment: Useful info at: [Fortran: Difference between include and modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662371/fortran-difference-between-include-and-modules#15668209)

Comment: `cat *.f > module.f`, add `module`, `end module` and `contains`, try to compile. ???. profit or fix the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a formatted comment than an answer, but you could try writing a source file something like this

```
module this_will_end_in_tears

contains

include 'subroutine1.f'
include 'subroutine2.f'
include 'subroutine2.f'
...

end module this_will_end_in_tears
```

If, as I suspect, the `.f` files contain fixed-form source, then you had better make sure the module is also in fixed-form.

I expect, as you may have guessed, that this will not compile the first time you try it, but it might (just might) save you a little time over doing the job right by, as you put it, *painstakingly writing out each sub/func* ...

Oh, and lest any of the Fortran-lovers out there cringe at this suggestion, note that I'm not saying it's a good way to proceed, just that it might save you a little time.

Good luck.

Comment: What would the difference be between `contains`...`include` like you've shown, and copy/pasting the subroutines into the module after the `contains` stmt? Aside from all of the source code being in the same file.

Comment: @MattP no difference

Comment: Unfortunately in my case the `.f` files are fixed form.  Perhaps there is a script or tool to update source code from older fortran to newer?

Comment: you can make the module fixed form. (that does not preclude using free form for code that `use`s the module so long as you keep the source in seperate files.

Comment: @MattP a drawback to the `include` approach is that build software (make) may not automatically see changes to the source as requiring a module rebuild. A minor issue but something to be aware of, especially if you plan on working on the source.

Answer (score 0):

I made this bash script that takes two parameters 'the module name' and 'the file extension' then builds a module file. It's presently made for fixed-format.  All the source files must be present in the same directory as the script.  Of course you can modify it to be more flexible.

```
name=$1
ext=$2
modsrc=$name.$ext
echo -e "      MODULE $name\n" > $modsrc
echo -e "          implicit none\n" >> $modsrc
echo -e "          contains\n" >> $modsrc
for i in *.f;
do
   if [ "$i" != "$modsrc" ]; then
       echo -e "         include '$i'\n" >> $modsrc
   fi
done
echo -e "       END MODULE $name\n" >> $modsrc
```

Answer (score -1):

I usually tackle things by compiling even .f90 code as -fixed. Then usually add in INTENT and IMPLICIT NONE. Almost always I have D-Lines for debug which seems to work easiest for me with -fixed form. Later adding in alignment pragmas and OpenMP reduction clauses and related vector stuff.