# Why should I use "use, only" in Fortran

Tags: fortran

In python a statement like this:

```
from module import function354
```

makes sense, because Python is an interpreter language and I don't want python to load all 353 other functions.

Fortran has a similar construct:

```
use module, only : function354
```

Why would I use this? The compiler creates a *.mod file anyway, compiling all function. Is there any performance advantage (in compile or run time) if I specify an `only`-statement?

I can see that it might be helpful to avoid naming conflict, but other than that I don't really see the point.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] to get more audience, the question is not version specific anyway (and Fortran 90 is not modern anymore).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you USE Fortran 90 module data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240510/how-do-you-use-fortran-90-module-data)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Two main reasons

1. To avoid name conflicts, as you mention but seem to think unimportant. In a large, complex code anything that helps maintainability is a bonus, so `use, only` is a useful addition to aid this
2. It automatically documents where an entity comes from. Given a large, complex code to read for the first time I can almost guarantee you'll be spending time working out what comes from which module, so `use, only` is a nice feature to aid code readability

You don't just want fast code - as important is maintainability, and more important is correctness!

Comment: So it speeds up compile time?

Comment: That's not what I said at all. But maybe, maybe not.

Answer (score 4):

### **Disclaimer:**

Someone has already pointed (correctly) in the comments that `use rename => name` can be used independently of `use, only`. Like this:

```
use module, f354 => function354
```

I am keeping the answer because it could be useful as complementary information on the `use` statement for someone that lands here.

---

### **Original Answer:**

Just for completeness, there is another feature that `use, only` provides, that is the ability to rename imported names with locally-bound names (*only is not needed for this, see **disclaimer** above*).

Like this:

```
use module, only: f354 => function354
```

That has proven useful for me in several different scenarios:

1. Resolve specific name ambiguities when two used modules provide types or functions with the same name.
   Example:

   ```
   use module1, only: m1_init => initialize
   use module2, only: m2_init => initialize
   ```
2. Use short names when the original name is too long, too cryptic or when it is used very often in your program.
   Example (from [fgsl](https://doku.lrz.de/display/PUBLIC/FGSL+-+A+Fortran+interface+to+the+GNU+Scientific+Library) and [lapack](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/)):

   ```
   use fgsl, only: stride => fgsl_aux_vector_double_stride      ! too long
   use lapack, only: solve => dgesvx                            ! too cryptic
   use iso_c_binding, only: i32 => c_int32_t, i64 => c_int64_t  ! too frequent
   ```
3. Make it easier to refactor or use conditional compilation / templating:
   Example (from [Fortran-lang/stdlib](https://stdlib.fortran-lang.org/)):

   ```
   use iso_fortran_env, only: sp => real32, dp => real64, qp => real128
   ! If we decide later to use iso_c_binding instead of iso_fortran_env:
   ! use iso_c_binding, only: sp => c_float, dp => c_double, qp => c_float128
   ```

Comment: Renaming does not require `only`.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know that. Do you recommend to delete the answer or edit and place a disclaimer at the start?

Comment: Just use `use module, f354 => function354