Is it possible (or even wise) to "encapsulate" constants from a module for use in a USE : ONLY statement?
Below is the framework of my module source.  I know how to do a "use : only" to draw in functions and subroutines from it as needed. What I don't know how to do is code the module so that I could draw in only the two constants at the top with a USE and ignore the functions and subroutines, should I wish to do so. Is there a source construct for doing this? (Using gfortran, if that makes a difference.)
Or do I need to have all the constants on their own module file, so they can be brought in independently of anything else?
a module QBtools
    implicit none

!module constants
integer, parameter  :: MAXSIZE = 500 !max allowed length of input record
integer, parameter  :: FIELDSIZE = 150 !max allowed length of individual fields from input record

contains




function QBgetfield(record,desired_field) result(fieldbuffer)

!function code here

endfunction QBgetfield



function getWINenv(request) result(varout)

!function code here

end function getWINenv


subroutine QBTrmlfs(filein)

!function code here

end subroutine QBTrmlfs

function QBfieldcount(record) result(counter)

!function code here

endfunction QBfieldcount

function QBstrip(str) result(strout)

!function code here

end function QBstrip



end module QBtools



Why do you think use, only : may apply only to functions and subroutines, instead of any module entity?

Possible? Yes, as the comments and answer show. Wise? I would say yes - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686745/why-should-i-use-use-only-in-fortran/51692422#51692422

Have you done any experiments?
module foo

   implicit none  ! <-- Always included to force declaration of entities.
   private        ! <-- Always included to hide everything in the module
   public pi, ln2 ! <-- Entities in module that are visible through USE

   real, parameter :: pi  = 0.6931
   real, parameter :: ln2 = 3.1415
end module foo

program bah
   use foo, only : pi, ln2
   print *, pi, ln2
end program bah


Oh, OK. I've see this before. It just didn't click. Thanks.
