# Cant figure out Tweepy Twitter Search API code

Tags: python, api, search, twitter, tweepy

I am very new to Python having taught it to myself just a few weeks ago. I have tried to cobble together some simple script using Tweepy to do various things with the Twitter API. I have been trying to get the Search API working but to no avail. I have the following code just to simply Search the last 7 days of Twitter for keywords.

```
# 1.Import required libs and used objects/libs 
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import API
from tweepy import Cursor



#2. GET or input App keys and tokens. Here keys/tokens are pasted from Twitter.
ckey = 'key'
csecret = 'secret'
atoken = 'token'
asecret =  'secret'

# 3. Set authorization tokens. 
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

#4. Define API. 
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#5. Define list or library.

for tweets in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q = '#IS', count = 100,
                           result_type ='recent').items():
print tweet.text
```

Every time I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jbutk_001/Desktop/Tweety Test/tweepy streaming.py", line 25, in <module>
     result_type ='recent')).items():
   File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\tweepy\cursor.py", line 22, in __init__
    raise TweepError('This method does not perform pagination')
TweepError: This method does not perform pagination
```

I also tried

```
for tweets in tweepy.Cursor(api.search(q = '#IS', count = 100,
                           result_type ='recent')).items():
print tweet.text
```

But then I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jbutk_001/Desktop/Tweety Test/tweepy streaming.py", line 25, in   <module>
    result_type ='recent').items():
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\tweepy\cursor.py", line 181, in next
     self.current_page = self.page_iterator.next()
   File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\tweepy\cursor.py", line 101, in next
    old_parser = self.method.__self__.parser
 AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__self__'
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction, this has been driving me nuts for the past few days.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are importing some things wrong, you might want to read more about how import works:
[What are good rules of thumb for Python imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193919/what-are-good-rules-of-thumb-for-python-imports)

A working example of how to make this kind of search work:

```
import tweepy

CONSUMER_KEY = 'key'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'secret'
ACCESS_KEY = 'accesskey'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'accesssecret'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                       q="#IS",
                       count=100,
                       result_type="recent",
                       include_entities=True,
                       lang="en").items():
print tweet.tweet
```

Also, I would recommend to avoid spaces in filenames, instead of "tweepy streaming.py" go for something like "tweepy_streaming.py".