# What is the difference, if any, between these 2 ways of importing modules in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

While reading some python code, I encountered 2 ways of importing user-defined modules.

The first one;

```
import config
```

The second one;

```
from config import *
```

What is the difference between the two? What happens if both lines of code are present? Any side effect?

Comment: The second way will pollute your current namespace with almost everything that is in config.

Comment: @Marcin: When I want to use variable declared in config module like this `config.variable`, `from config import *` cannot work. Does that mean one has to use `import config` in this situation, even if it is a big pollutant? Are there better ways to avoid pollution?

Comment: There is some pretty decent documentation with examples about this available at [python.org](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).  The down vote isn't mine, but because this information is widely available and you don't mention looking anywhere else for it, you may attract down votes.

Comment: `from config import *` might not import everything. By default, private variables (i.e. those starting with single underscore) are not being imported.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are good rules of thumb for Python imports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193919/what-are-good-rules-of-thumb-for-python-imports)

Comment: `-1` for telling people not to downvote. If you are "in danger of being blocked" perhaps you should put more effort into researching your questions *before* asking.

Comment: @Lego Stormtroopr: Ok. I will remove that part. I am not exactly telling people not to downvote. I am just telling them to at least tell me why they are downvoting if they want to downvote which is what you have done. THanks, anyway.

Comment: Just been banned from Stack Overflow. Sigh ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say there's a module named `unicorn`, with global contents `stack`, `over`, and `flow`.

- If you do `import unicorn`, these can be accessed as `unicorn.stack`, `unicorn.over`, and `unicorn.flow`.
- If you do `import unicorn as U`, these can be accessed as `U.stack`, `U.over`, and `U.flow`.
- If you do `from unicorn import stack`, the `stack` object from `unicorn` is copied into the global variable `stack`.
- If you do `from unicorn import *`, `stack` and other all global objects in the module (except private ones whose names begin with an underscore) are copied into your global namespace. This can be fine, but later updates to the `unicorn` module might add things that cause your program to behave unexpectedly. For example, if you have variables called `user` and `server`, a future update to `unicorn` that adds `super`, `user`, `server`, and `fault` may cause it to misbehave.
- If you do `from unicorn import stack, over, flow`, only those things you specify get copied in, and your program keeps working even after more things get added to `unicorn`.
- If you do `from unicorn import stack as H`, you get `stack` from the `unicorn` module, but in your program's global namespace it's called `H`. This can help keep your lines under 80 characters if you're using a particular function or variable really often.

Answer (score -1):

The code

```
import config
```

just import the module named config,if you want to use a method of it,you need to use something like `myname = config.getName()` .

The code

```
from config import *
```

will  import  everything exported by `config` to current namespace. Now if you want to use the getName method in config,the code is something like  `myname = getName()`

We always use the first importing way,because you can use different methods with the same name exported by more than one module. For example,we can use two `getName` method below:

```
import config
import mydata

print config.getName()#print Jim
print mydata.getName()#print Tom
```

When you do it in the second way like,the last import code will import the `getName` method replace the one you has imported by the first import code:

```
from config import *
from mydata import *

print getName()#print Tom
```

So you can see,the current namespace is polluted by the second way.

Comment: This is wrong, the latter won't work as `config` and `mydata` aren't defined in that space. They won't print anything and `print config.getName()` will throw an exception.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr so sorry that I just copy the code,and do not modify it.:(