# Why use `import as` on some python modules but not others?

Tags: python, module, python-import

Why are packages like `glob` and `psycopg2` not shortened on import? Is there any other reason than convention or personal preference? Perhaps best practice?

---

**Example: For the sake of readability and reducing the overhead of loading an entire package:**

```py
# Best practice
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
model_score = r2_score(arg1, arg2)

# Similarly, to keep names short
import sklearn
model_score = sklearn.metrics.r2_score(arg1, arg2)
```

**Similarl example: long package names are just shortened, especially if many part of the package are used**

```py
# Best practice
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaboard as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(dictobject)
w_avg = np.average(mylist, weights=w)
sns.heatmap(df)
plt.show()

# instead of
import pandas
import numpy
import seaboard
import matplotlib

df = pandas.DataFrame(dictobject)
w_avg = numpy.average(mylist, weights=w)
seaborn.heatmap(df)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

**Why do we not do the same with glob?**

```
# Shouldn't this be best practice?
import glob.glob as gl
jpgs = gl('path/*.jpg')

# But instead this seems more prominent:
import glob
jpgs = glob.glob('path/*.jpg')
```

Perhaps in case if we needed one of `glob.glob`'s lesser know cousins (`glob.iglob` or `glob.escape`), we could `import glob as gl` (and then use `gl.iglob` or `gl.escape`).

This question: *[python import module vs import module as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469611/python-import-module-vs-import-module-as)*, did not answer my question.

Comment: `"Is there any other reason than convention or personal preference?"` No, which is why I voted to close this question as "opinion-based"

Comment: It's not that some modules are shortened while others are not. Modules such as `glob` simply define a class with the same name as the module. So `glob.glob` means, inside package `glob` access class `glob`, similar to how `pandas.DataFrame` means inside module `pandas` access class `DataFrame`. Everything else is based on preference or what module methods and structures you need access to.

Comment: @h0r53 that is not what OP is asking. They ask why it is a "convention" to see `import pandas as pd` but not `import glob as g`

Comment: Then yes, this is opinion based and not well suited here

Comment: Thanks for your input. My question is **"Are there reasons for doing X?"** and the objective answer seems to be: **"No, it's purely convention and personal preference"**. I dont believe it is opinion based.

Comment: So you don't "believed" the answer just because it doesn't fit with what you thought is  the "real" answer? then why bother asking at all?

Comment: See the accepted answer. That is all I was looking for. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's purely convention and personal preference

Comment: Good on ya Luke!