# Redundant interface to python module

Tags: python, import, packaging

I have a package with the following structure

```
package/
│
└───__init__.py
│
└───sub/
    └───__init__.py
    │
    └───XWrap.py # implements class X
    └───YWrap.py # implements class Y
```

The first `__init__.py` looks like this:

```
from . import sub
```

The second `__init__.py` looks like this:

```
from .XWrap import X
from .YWrap import Y
```

Doing this, the user sees the following

```
package
│
└───sub
    └───X
    └───XWrap
    └───Y
    └───YWrap
```

I would like to have a cleaner interface where I don't see `YWrap` and `XWrap`. How can I achieve this?

This is the same question asked in a comment here: [Python packages - import by class, not file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122/python-packages-import-by-class-not-file)
but couldn't find a definite answer.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "see" in this case? eg. you don't want it to autocomplete, or you want the import to fail? Perhaps underscore the files or use `__all__`.

Comment: Above I just used the `dir` function to explore the module structure. So I guess I want the import to fail. If I am not mistaken `__all__` applies to imports of the form `from package import *` right?

Comment: I'd say it's likely not very pythonic to attempt to hide things from `dir` and fail imports (if even possible). I'd suggest just call it `_XWrap.py` and `_YWrap.py` if you don't want things to be user facing.

Comment: I may end up doing that, but it doesn't satisfy me. Most files in my project will need an underscore and I feel there should be a better way.

Comment: Another suggestion then - have a different folder such as `_sub` for all the private stuff, and import from that into the main `sub`.